# How to throw spring security AuthenticationException or proceed to unsuccessfulAuthentication

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-security

I want to throw `AuthenticationException` in my overriden `attemptAuthentication` from my class that extends`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` method but I don't know how to do so. 
My code:

```
@Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        if(portService.getOpenPort()==null){
            //'AuthenticationException' is abstract; cannot be instantiated
            throw new AuthenticationException("No free port found");
        }
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }
```

Is it only meant to be used in try catch clause, If so is there any other way to make filter proceed to `unsuccessfulAuthentication`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create your own subclass of `AuthenticationException`, like `BadCredentialsException` does.

You can probably create a:

```java
public class NoOpenPortAuthenticationException extends AuthenticationException {

    public NoOpenPortAuthenticationException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

}
```

And in your code do: `throw new NoOpenPortAuthenticationException("No free port found");`